# Ubuntu-Server Backups Tool

Tags: backup

I wan to backup my whole server. I don't use LVM. I want to exclude some specific folders but backup the rest. I dont wanna use duply.
Is there any good tool I could use for that? I need to backup to a remote backup server. The backups should be encrypted.

Can rdiff-backup also upload to a remote server using sftp?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions,
Rsnapshot, duplicity, attic, bup, rsync, tar are good tools.

Regarding rdiff-backup allowing uploading to an sftp server. It can upload via ssh. You need a bit more than just sftp access. From the documentation,

```
rdiff-backup /some/local-dir hostname.net::/whatever/remote-dir
```

Where hostname.net is the remote server.

---

Now, some questions you should ask yourself when doing this.

- Is this for an online backup or an offline backup?
- do you need incremental backups?
- do you need encryption?
- If you have things like databases, how will they behave while you're taking a snapshot? Should you create a dump before the actual backup?
- Is there value to data that's on RAM? Do you need to force anything to write to disk?

The more information you provide, the better we can help you.

Comment: I need it for online backup to a remote server supporting sftp, webdav and samba/cif. the problem is whenever i try to automount webdav or samba, the server doesnt boot anymore. so i wanna stick with sftp. also i need encryption and incremental backups. i have databases but i use automysqlbackup and backup that directory too. i dont need data from RAM I think.